# Interpretation of design matrix

Tags: experiment-design

I'm planning to conduct an experiment, where I have four IVs.

$IV_{1}$ to $IV_{3}$ have 3 levels each, and $IV_{4}$ has 2 levels.
I want to apply d-optimal design here,
because the full factorial experiment costs a lot (54 runs),

I read some web pages such as https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section5/pri521.htm.
Here I wonder why design matrix takes symmetrical values between +1 and -1,
and how these values can be interpreted algebraically.

Can these values be treated as continuous?

Or are they something like dummy variables?

And how variance-covariance matrix can be calculated and interpreted?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer.  The nomenclature of the -1 and +1 is to represent the low and high values of the test range.  It can be used for both discrete or continuous variables.  So yes these can be treated as continuous.
For continuous variable, it is also helpful in normalizing parameters of widely different magnitudes(such a drug dose and hours of sleep).  Since each variable is normalized to the same scale, it makes for easy comparison of effect given the experimental range.
For continuous variables it can be extend to -1, +1, 0 for low, high and middle value. etc. for more variables. For basic DOE work, low and high and the occasional middle is usually  all that is needed.